# Strange url rewrite issue in new wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I have just setup a new Wordpress site in an AWS EC2 host with the following DNS host name:

```
http://ec2-34-230-30-128.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
```

Everything was working fine so I just went ahead and setup a friendly domain name:

```
wordpress.devtechperu.com
```

that points to the DNS host name using a CNAME (I use AWS Route 53).

However, now when I navigate to wordpress.devtechperu.com, Wordpress shows the site with `http://ec2-34-230-30-128.compute-1.amazonaws.com/` in the browser URL!!

I have never run into this issue with other webservers so I guess WordPress is rewriting the url somehow?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress, by default (if a rewrite handler like `mod_rewrite` in Apache is enabled), redirects to the URL that you have set as `Site Address`.

After changing the DNS records, you should also update the `Site Address` and the `WordPress Address` values in the dashboard by going to Settings → General. Other method is changing those values in the database, they are in the `wp_options` table as `siteurl` and `home`.

For further information about changing WordPress Site URL check out [Changing The Site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the default address in the Wordpress Settings and this fixed the issue