# AWS WP not found

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have WP set in amazon EC2 and it was working fine.
Set up custom theme, changed my domain to point to wp install address.

My domain worked just fine, but i wanted to change the url shown on page from ip address to my domain name.

I tried changing functions.php with

```
<?php
update_option('siteurl','http://example.com');
update_option('home','http://example.com');
?>
```

and now neither domain or ip address will connect from browser.
i cant even get to admin page.

SSH and FTP still work fine. so some kind of addres error i guess.

I need to get my WP site back, bonus points if you can also tell me how to change that url...

Comment: First, remove those lines from your `functions.php`, then check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901441/strange-url-rewrite-issue-in-new-wordpress-site/45901863).

Comment: @Mithc i removed it over an hour ago but the site is still unreachable :(

Comment: And did you update the database values?

Comment: @Mithc im looking at the database now, you happen to know how i change a spesific value? there is lots of very odd looking data here

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bMdnL

Comment: Check out the SO question I mentioned above, the answer describes what table and which records you should update :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152948/discussion-between-mithc-and-clomez).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were problems with my database, huge thanks to @Mithc, i dont think it very common to encounter problem like this, but please read the comment thread above if you encounter this the problem