# Pointing route 53 dns to wordpress site in AWS EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I need help with WordPress site on EC2 which I have pointed to route 53 DNS name. I am able to access the Wordpress site through the new DNS but other links are still going with the instance name. Can you please help me with how to convert all the links to the new domain name.

For example:

> EC2 Wordpress site: http://ec123-3-54-45-21.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
>
> Domain name: myblog.com

I have already pointed my myblog.com(route 53) to Wordpress site(http://ec123-3-54-45-21.compute-1.amazonaws.com/) and it works fine.

I am able to see the site with a new URL.

But when I click on any of the blog links on my site it points to EC2 URL(http://ec123-3-54-45-21.compute-1.amazonaws.com/) and shows the ec2 URL on the browser instead of myblog.com URL.

Please help to resolve these issues.

Comment: I resolved this issue by referring to questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901441/strange-url-rewrite-issue-in-new-wordpress-site?rq=1
It was helpful!!